# How to create loading screen when i click on login button and page should be redirect to Dashboard?

Tags: android, flutter

Everyone I am new in flutter. How can create loading screen on login page. when i click on login button then it should be redirect on Dashboard with loading screen. I am trying to create loading screen in flutter. When I click on login button then loading screen show be show and after loading screen it should be redirect on Dashboard.....

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_spinkit/flutter_spinkit.dart';
import 'package:flutternew/dashboard.dart';
import 'package:flutternew/forget_password.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'bezierContainer.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class ShowLoading extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Loading View'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: _circularProgressIndicator(),
        ));
  }

  Widget _circularProgressIndicator() {
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>(debugLabel: '_homekey');
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  String _email;
  String _password;
  final TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();
  var modal = Container();
  showAlertDialog(BuildContext context, String message) {
    Widget okButton = FlatButton(
      child: Text("OK"),
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
    );
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text("Error"),
      content: Text(message),
      actions: [
        okButton,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _formSetupWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            controller: emailController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: "Username",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 25),
                fillColor: Color(0xFFFAFAfA),
                filled: true),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            validator: (val) {
              if (val.length == 0)
                return "Please enter email";
              else if (!val.contains("@"))
                return "Please enter valid email";
              else
                return null;
            },
            onSaved: (val) => _email = val,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          TextFormField(
            controller: passwordController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: "Password",
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 25),
                fillColor: Color(0xFFFAFAfA),
                filled: true),
            obscureText: true,
            validator: (val) {
              if (val.length == 0)
                return "Please enter password";
              else if (val.length <= 5)
                return "Your password should be more then 6 char long";
              else
                return null;
            },
            onSaved: (val) => _password = val,
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
          ),
          ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: 500.0,
            height: 60.0,
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: new Text("Login",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 23.0)),
              color: Colors.blueAccent,
              highlightColor: Colors.blueAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                if (emailController.text != " " ||
                    passwordController.text != " ") {
                  signIn(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  signIn(String email, pass) async {
    int visible = 0;

    final sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    Map data = {'email': email, 'password': pass};
    var jsonResponse = null;
    var response = await http
        .post("https://abcdef.com/iot/api/login", body: data);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      if (jsonResponse != null) {
        if (jsonResponse['success'] == 1) {
          sharedPreferences.setString("token", jsonResponse['data']['token']);

          Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Dashboard()),
              (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
        } else {
          String message = jsonResponse['message'];
          showAlertDialog(context, message);
        }
      }
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      print(response.body);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Center(
      child: SpinKitWave(color: Colors.white, type: SpinKitWaveType.start),
    );
    var assetsImage = new AssetImage('assets/logo.png');
    var image = new Image(image: assetsImage, width: 150.0, height: 150.0);
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      height: height,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
              top: -height * .15,
              right: -MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .4,
              child: BezierContainer()),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 70),
                  new Center(
                    child: image,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  _formSetupWidget(context),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: FlatButton(
                      child: Text("Forgot Password?"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                    Forget_password()),
                            (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: height * .055),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what the issue is. See [ask], [help/on-topic], [mcve].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create class

```
class LoaderDialog {

  static Future<void> showLoadingDialog(BuildContext context, GlobalKey key) async {
    var wid = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2;
    return showDialog<void>(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 130 , right: 130),
            child: Dialog(
              key: key,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              child: Container(
                width: 60.0,
                height: 60.0,
                child:  Image.asset(
                  'images/loaderOld.gif',
                  height: 60,
                  width: 60,
                ),
              )
            ),
          );
        },
    );
  }
}
```

How to Call:
In your Class(Where you want to show the loader).

```
  final GlobalKey<State> _LoaderDialog = new GlobalKey<State>();
```

// Show

```
LoaderDialog.showLoadingDialog(context, _LoaderDialog);
```

// Hide

```
  Navigator.of(_LoaderDialog.currentContext,rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. your code is working but gif is not showing. I have directory and gif image also.

Comment: You can use other image or any Widget. And please accept the answer, it will help others also.

Comment: hi @kumar lokesh rathod I have post another question. Can you solved it?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62591401/how-to-enable-and-disable-button-in-gridview-using-flutter