# How to enable and disable button in GridView using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I have created buttons in grid view using flutter. Now I want to change color of button when I click on button. Same like active use in HTML. When I click on button then button should be show in active state and when I click on another button then first button will be disable and current button will be enable.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'My Mitsu',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          actions: <Widget>[
            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text("Logout",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20.0)),
              onPressed: () async {
                log_out();
              },
              color: Colors.white,
            )
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column(children: [
          Expanded(
            child: GridView.count(
              crossAxisCount: countValue,
              mainAxisSpacing: 35.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 35.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 40.0, 40.0, 20.0),
              childAspectRatio: (aspectWidth / aspectHeight),
              children: <Widget>[
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Send Lift to Parking',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    onPress(0);
                    showShortToast();
                  },
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    onPress(1);
                    showShortToast();
                  },
                  child: Text('Send Lift to 1st Floor',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    onPress(2);
                    showShortToast();
                  },
                  child: Text('Send Lift to 2st Floor',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    onPress(3);
                    showShortToast();
                  },
                  child: Text('Send Lift to 3st Floor',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    onPress(4);
                    showShortToast();
                  },
                  child: Text('Send Lift to 4st Floor',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    onPress(5);
                    showShortToast();
                  },
                  child: Text('Send Lift to 5st Floor',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    onPress(6);
                    showShortToast();
                  },
                  child: Text('Send Lift to 6st Floor',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    onPress(7);
                    showShortToast();
                  },
                  child: Text('Send Lift to 7st Floor',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't pass a function to the onPressed property of the button, the button will be automatically disabled,
(don't pass = passing null)

```
///button#1
FlatButton(
 //change color according to state
 color: button1Enabled? Colors.green:Colors.red;
 onPressed: button1Enabled? (){ } : null;
)

///button#2
FlatButton(
 onPressed: (){
  setState(){
   button1Enabled = !button1Enabled;
  }
 }
)
```

Comment: color should be changed when i click on button

Answer (score 0):

Create you button like this

```
RaisedButton(
    onPressed: () {
       onPressed(1);
    },
    color: currentIndex == 1 ? bottonColor : null,
    child: Text('Send Lift to 1st Floor',
           style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
),
```

and create onPress fuction like this

```
onPressed(String floor) {
setState(() {
  currentIndex = int.parse(floor);
  bottonColor = Colors.red;
});
```

}

create two variable outside the class currentIndex and buttonColor

```
int currentIndex = 0;
Color bottonColor;
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

   }
}
```